# Store all array values into a single variable as CSV in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, csv

I have an array containing numbers 1-5 (sometimes more). All the members in the array can be displayed using the php function `foreach`. But, how can I display all the members of my array by storing it in a single variable as csv (like`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`), and thereby printing that variable only?

Comment: do you only want to know what's inside the array or do you actually have to work with that variable afterwards?

Comment: i want to work with it afterwards :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the function `implode()`.

**For example**

```
$csv_var = implode(', ', $array);
```

Have a look at the [Manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).